# Total all value in combo box using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a program that needs to compute all the total selected in combo box to text box using javascript..my problem is its not working it wont total..i need your help guys..im still learning.

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" name="frm" id="frm" >
  <input type="text" name="name" id="query" />
  <select name="optA">
  <option></option>
  <option onclick="optTotal()" value="1">1</option>
  <option onclick="optTotal()" value="2">2</option>
  <option onclick="optTotal()" value="3">3</option>
  </select>
    |
  <select name="optB">
  <option></option>
  <option onclick="optTotal()" value="1">1</option>
  <option onclick="optTotal()" value="2">2</option>
  <option onclick="optTotal()" value="3">3</option>
  </select>
    |
  <select name="optC">
  <option></option>
  <option onclick="optTotal()" value="1">1</option>
  <option onclick="optTotal()" value="2">2</option>
  <option onclick="optTotal()" value="3">3</option>
  </select>
    |
  <select name="optD">
  <option></option>
  <option onclick="optTotal()" value="1">1</option>
  <option onclick="optTotal()" value="2">2</option>
  <option onclick="optTotal()" value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="total" id="total" onKeyUp="optTotal()" />
  <input type="submit" value="Test" name="calculate" id="press" />
</form>
```

here is my javascript code:

```
<script>
function optTotal()
{
var a1 = document.querySelector('input[name="optA"]:selected');
var b1 = document.querySelector('input[name="optB"]:selected');
var c1 = document.querySelector('input[name="optC"]:selected');
var d1 = document.querySelector('input[name="optD"]:selected');
if (a1 != null)
    a1 = parseFloat(a1.value);
else
    a1 = 0;
if (b1 != null)
    b1 = parseFloat(b1.value);
else
    b1 = 0;
if (c1 != null)
    c1 = parseFloat(c1.value);
else
    c1 = 0;
if (d1 != null)
    d1 = parseFloat(d1.value);
else
    d1 = 0;

document.frm.total.value=parseFloat(a1)+parseFloat(b1)+parseFloat(c1)+parseFloat(d1);
}
</script>
```

whats the problem with my code??anyone guys?

Comment: why there is onlclick on every option. cant we put it on select.

Comment: You are free to choose the answer that helped you, just check also my answer as its not dependent on how many options you have. Also it uses no inline script and that is better practise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a proper checking of values here is a working code. Here is a demo http://jsbin.com/uriFida/2/edit

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post" action="index.php" name="frm" id="frm" >
  <input type="text" name="name" id="query" />
  <select name="optA" onchange="optTotal()">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
    |
  <select name="optB" onchange="optTotal()">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
    |
  <select name="optC" onchange="optTotal()">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
    |
  <select name="optD" onchange="optTotal()">
  <option></option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="total" id="total" onKeyUp="optTotal()" />
  <input type="submit" value="Test" name="calculate" id="press" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
function optTotal()
{
    var a1 = document.querySelector('select[name="optA"]');
    var b1 = document.querySelector('select[name="optB"]');
    var c1 = document.querySelector('select[name="optC"]');
    var d1 = document.querySelector('select[name="optD"]');

    if (a1.value && a1.value != "")
        a1 = parseFloat(a1.value);
    else
        a1 = 0;

    if (b1.value && b1.value != "")
        b1 = parseFloat(b1.value);
    else
        b1 = 0;

    if (c1.value && c1.value != "")
        c1 = parseFloat(c1.value);
    else
        c1 = 0;

    if (d1.value && d1.value != "")
        d1 = parseFloat(d1.value);
    else
        d1 = 0;

      document.getElementById("total").value = parseFloat(a1)+parseFloat(b1)+parseFloat(c1)+parseFloat(d1);

}
```

Comment: @eloginko no worries. please dont' forget to upvote if you find the answer helpfull :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
var formSelects = document.querySelectorAll('#frm select');
var Sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < formSelects.length; i++) {
    if(formSelects[i].value != '') Sum += parseFloat(formSelects[i].value);
}
```

**My suggestion** is you remove all inline script and use like:

```
window.onload = function () {
    function optTotal() {
        var Sum = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < formSelects.length; i++) {
            if (formSelects[i].value != '') Sum += parseFloat(formSelects[i].value);
        }
        alert(Sum);
    }

    var formSelects = document.querySelectorAll('#frm select');
    for (var i = 0; i < formSelects.length; i++) {
        formSelects[i].onchange = optTotal;
    }

};
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G87rK/1/)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="index.php" name="frm" id="frm" >
  <input type="text" name="name" id="query" />
  <select name="optA" onchange="optTotal()">
  <option></option>
  <option  value="1">1</option>
  <option  value="2">2</option>
  <option  value="3">3</option>
  </select>
    |
  <select name="optB" onchange="optTotal()">
  <option></option>
  <option  value="1">1</option>
  <option  value="2">2</option>
  <option  value="3">3</option>
  </select>
    |
  <select name="optC" onchange="optTotal()">
  <option></option>
  <option  value="1">1</option>
  <option  value="2">2</option>
  <option  value="3">3</option>
  </select>
    |
  <select name="optD" onchange="optTotal()">
  <option></option>
  <option  value="1">1</option>
  <option  value="2">2</option>
  <option  value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  <input type="text" name="total" id="total" onKeyUp="optTotal()" />
  <input type="submit" value="Test" name="calculate" id="press" />
</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function optTotal()
{
    var a1 = document.getElementsByName('optA')[0].value;
    var b1 = document.getElementsByName('optB')[0].value;
    var c1 = document.getElementsByName('optC')[0].value;
    var d1 = document.getElementsByName('optD')[0].value;
    var total = 0;
    console.log(a1)
    if (a1 != '')
        total += parseFloat(a1);
    if (b1 != '')
        total += parseFloat(b1);
    if (c1 != '')
        total += parseFloat(c1);
    if (d1 != '')
        total += parseFloat(d1);

    document.frm.total.value=total;
}
```